# stopImmediatePropagation doesn't work for SimpleButton

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, simplebutton

I'm trying to cancel the event in this actionscript3 code:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public function Main()
    {

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    protected function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver, true, int.MAX_VALUE);

        var btn:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(
            createBtnState(0x0000FF), 
            createBtnState(0x00FFFF),
            createBtnState(0x00FF00),
            createBtnState(0x0000FF));
        btn.x = stage.stageWidth - btn.width >> 1;
        btn.y = stage.stageHeight - btn.height >> 1;
        addChild(btn);
    }
    private function createBtnState(color:uint):Sprite
    {
        var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
        s.graphics.beginFill(color, 1);
        s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,20);
        s.graphics.endFill();
        return s;
    }

    protected function onOver(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation(); //Don't work
    }
}
```

how to cancel the event hover the button? 
In this example, the button responds when you hover.

Comment: I am trying to prevent the switching on overState. ROLL_OVER also no results

Comment: I'm not sure how the `SimpleButton` handles its states internally,  but typically if one doesn't want the state to change, they would set it's `enabled` property to `false`.

Comment: You could also change the state manually (eg  `btn.overState = btn.upState`)

Comment: there is no possibility to get all possible active buttons

Answer (score 0):

your hover event seem to be added on the Main Not the Button.
Try putting the event listener on the btn you declared.

```
protected function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
{
    //this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver, true, int.MAX_VALUE);

    var btn:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(
        createBtnState(0x0000FF), 
        createBtnState(0x00FFFF),
        createBtnState(0x00FF00),
        createBtnState(0x0000FF));
    btn.x = stage.stageWidth - btn.width >> 1;
    btn.y = stage.stageHeight - btn.height >> 1;
    addChild(btn);

    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver, true, int.MAX_VALUE);
}
```